# Does Apache ActiveMQ support Windows Server 2022?

Tags: activemq-classic, windows-server-2022

I want to install ActiveMQ on Windows Server 2022 for my production. Does ActiveMQ support Windows Server 2022?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Apache ActiveMQ is a Java application so as long as your platform has a Java Virtual Machine (i.e. JVM) then it can run Apache ActiveMQ. The latest versions of Apache ActiveMQ require Java 11 although there are still fairly recent versions that support Java 8. Download links are:

- [ActiveMQ "Classic"](https://activemq.apache.org/components/classic/download/)
- [ActiveMQ Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/download/)